# Mortarboard Day Period

Tags: discussion, badges

At the risk of sounding like a complainer:

I just got (over) 200 rep.  It's 5:23PM here in Colorado, yet the rep I received just an hour ago is listed in "yesterday", and the most recent 30 in "today".

Am I missing a time zone setting, or is this something I have to remember when considering pursuing a badge?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because Stack Overflow time is based on UTC time, and not the time where the user is located. So it is in fact "yesterday" UTC time.

[UTC Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)